# Set the height and width seperatly for a box-shadow?

Tags: css

I need to create a div that hold a dynamic amount of content with a box shadow on either side and the bottom, the top hasn't. I also need the shadow on the sides to sharply appear slightly down the div and for none of the shadows to overlay each other which darkens the shade of the particular area.
Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/EdwardG_Jones/TBfWm/
 
I've tried the following way, which works, however it doesn't cover the corners and isn't a instant transition rather a gradual one as the gradient fades in:
http://jsfiddle.net/EdwardG_Jones/WC2ja/2/

```
box-shadow: 12px 5px 5px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75),  -12px 5px 5px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75), 0    7px 5px -5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

I'll probably end up using an image for the bottom gradient and somehow create another div that sits on top of the shadow at the top to hide it without hiding the content. Not sure how I'm gonna do that. Especially in drupal, meaning its more difficult to manually hard code the divs in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR do whatever you need to to make the bottom, left and right borders look right and then just hide the top border with this hacky code:

```
div{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75)
}
div:before{
     content: ""; 
     width: 200px; 
     height: 5px; 
     background: white;  
     position: absolute; 
     margin-top: -6px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WC2ja/9/).

Then feel really guilty about using it.

Comment: Hmm, I tried putting your code into Fiddle but it didn't seem to work. Could you link a working demonstration? Also could you explain whats happening/why it works?

Comment: My bad, mucked up the pasting, fixed now. Added a JSFiddle link too.

All it's doing is placing a box above the div (overlaying it) with solid white colour to simply "hide" the shadow underneath. It's hacky because it's not really fixing the root issue, it's just covering up the mistakes. But it works! :P

Comment: Ok well that works if I wanted to get rid of just the top shadow, however :P I need the shadows down the sides to only appear slightly down the div, not right at the top. The gradient is also wrapping around the :before, creating little 'horns', if you will.

Comment: [This should help](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curls/).
It basically uses small div blocks behind the main one that are rotated with box shadow to make it seem as if the shadow is fading/withdrawing.